# How do I create a Service Account in Kubernetes and associate a Token to the new Service Account

Tags: kubernetes

I tried creating just a simple Service account in Kubernetes by running the command on my AWS EC2 cli `kubectl create serviceaccount jenkins --dry-run=client -o yaml > jenkins-sa.yaml` and I have my `kube/config` file on my `/home/ec2-user`.

I applied the new config jenkins-sa.yaml by running `kubectl apply -f jenkins-sa.yaml` and then I tried to see more info about the newly created service account by running  `kubectl describe serviceaccount jenkins` which displays some information but without the secret token that should be associated to the jenkins service account by default.

Please I would be grateful if someone can point out what i'm doing wrong because I'm pretty new to Kubernetes. Below is a screenshot

[image]

Comment: what if you do a kubectl create sa jenkins2, and paste the output of describe

Answer (score 4):

You have to create the token secret manually. Here is a YAML example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: jenkins-sa-token
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "jenkins"
```

This will create a sercvice account token secret for your jenkins service account with name `jenkins-sa-token`.

Comment: Can it be created in imperative manner, with `kubectl create secret` and a bunch of parameters?

Answer (score 3):

Starting Kubernetes 1.24, token is not generated by default. You can see the [changelog](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.24.md#urgent-upgrade-notes) for more details. You can manually create token using

```
Kubectl create token
```